# How to resolve this warning "Code will never be executed" in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, firebase

It shows a warning **Code will never be executed**. I checked 3 times my code but dont know how to resolve this warning?

```
[[[[self.dbRef child:@"Status"] child:user.uid] child:@"Details"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

            //Add Current User Image.....            
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=name,picture.height(100).width(100)" parameters:nil]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            //NSLog(@"Result is : %@",result);
            NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *) result;
            NSDictionary *data3 = [dictionary objectForKey: @"picture"];
            NSDictionary *data2 = [data3 objectForKey: @"data"];
            NSString *photoURL = (NSString *)[data2 objectForKey:@"url"];
            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: photoURL]];
            cell.imgUser.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imgData];
            [tableView reloadData];
        }];


        //Show current user name....
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=name,picture.height(100).width(100),name" parameters:nil]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            NSString *currentUName = snapshot.value[@"name"];
            NSArray *currentUNameArr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentUName];
            cell.lblUName.text = currentUNameArr[indexPath.row];
            [tableView reloadData];
        }];

} withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Comment: at which line you are getting that warning ?

Comment: In first line..

Comment: The problem is before the first line. Probably a condition which is always true or false, or a `return;` statement.

Answer (score -1):

You missed a bracket in the front, thats why it is giving that warning. Try the below code.

```
[[[[self.dbRef child:@"Status"] child:user.uid] child:@"Details"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    //Add Current User Image.....
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=name,picture.height(100).width(100)" parameters:nil]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        //NSLog(@"Result is : %@",result);
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *) result;
        NSDictionary *data3 = [dictionary objectForKey: @"picture"];
        NSDictionary *data2 = [data3 objectForKey: @"data"];
        NSString *photoURL = (NSString *)[data2 objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: photoURL]];
        cell.imgUser.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imgData];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }];


    //Show current user name....
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=name,picture.height(100).width(100),name" parameters:nil]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        NSString *currentUName = snapshot.value[@"name"];
        NSArray *currentUNameArr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentUName];
        cell.lblUName.text = currentUNameArr[indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }];

} withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Comment: What is different from the code in the question? And why?

Comment: added a bracket in the front. Otherwise the block wont get complete. The code in the question looks like on the fly.

Comment: I still don't see the difference. And the compiler won't accept missing brackets.